# Is there a way to stop time in Javascript, so I can test a function against DateTime.now()?

Tags: javascript, luxon

I have a function that returns DateTime.now() under certain conditions. I want to test that function but if I test it against DateTime.now(), it will create a flaky test. Is there any way I can freeze time for executing this specific test and then reset it?

Comment: no there isn't.

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for commenting. Is there any way I can test this without making it flaky?

Comment: Sample code for the function in question would be helpful, but I think you want to mock the DateTime.now function to return the same value each time it is called. Mocking it would essentially rewrite the function definition to whatever you specify it to be, which in your case would be returning a specific time value. See if this link helps, although I'm not sure if you're using jest: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2234

Comment: @SanchitBatra, thank you for the link. I am in fact using jest and was unaware of `@sinonjs/fake-timers`. That was exactly what I needed.